# Retrieving a request within an express controller to store file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have a express backend I am currently building. I created a router and controller system that process each and every request that comes through the server. I am currently trying to save image files that are sent with the profile as profile picture. I am currently integrating `multer` into my backend. I have the multer destination set but I am not sure how to grab the request that passing through in order to actually save the file before the request gets to the controller.

my app.js:

```
...
// app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'helloworld',
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000},
  saveUninitialized: false,
}))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(fileUpload());

app.use('/api/auth', AuthenticationRouter)
app.use('/api/user', UserRouter)
app.use('/api/profile', ProfileRouter)
app.use('/api/follow', FollowRouter)
app.use('/api/post', PostRouter)
app.use('/api/like', LikeRouter)
app.use('/api/edit', EditRouter)
app.use('/api/download', DownloadRouter)
app.use('/api/comment', CommentRouter)
```

the following is the routers page. this is the point where i am trying to grab the request and save the file that was sent with the request. I am not sure how to inject and grab the request object at this point
routers:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({dest:'../client/static/images/ProfilePictures'})

const router = require("express").Router()
const profileController = require("../../controllers/UserControllers/ProfileController.js");

router
  .route('/')
  .get(profileController.get)
  .post(upload,single(''), profileController.post)
  .delete(profileController.delete)
  .patch(profileController.patch)

module.exports = router;
```

controller:

```
const Profile = require("../../models/UserModels/Profiles.js")
const User = require('../../models/UserModels/Users.js')

const profileController = {
  post:(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files.profile_pic.name)
    let body = req.body
    let file = req.files.profile_pic
    Profile.create({
      profile_pic: file.name,
      f_name: body.f_name,
      l_name: body.l_name,
      bio: body.bio,
      location: body.location,
      sm_facebook: body.sm_facebook,
      sm_instagram: body.sm_instagram,
      sm_twitter: body.sm_twitter,
      sm_website: body.sm_website,
      followers: body.followers,
      following: body.following,
      photos: body.photos,
      downloads: body.downloads,
      edits: body.edits,
      userId: body.userId
    })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data).status(200)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      res.send(err).status(400)
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Instead of `upload,single('')`, it should be `upload.single('')`.

Multer will automatically parse the image and populate the `req.file` with the image upload data. However, in your controller, you are trying to access `req.files`. So, if you will upload multiple files, I would suggest that you switch from `upload.singe('')` to `upload.any()`, since `upload.any()` will populate `req.files` and not `req.file`.

You can change your router like this:

```
router
  .route('/')
  .get(profileController.get)
  .post(upload.any(), profileController.post)
  .delete(profileController.delete)
  .patch(profileController.patch)
```

And you can change your contoller like this:

```js
const profileController = {
  post:(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files)
    let file = req.files[0];
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: okay, so what I am understanding is that sinceI have the multer defined in the controller with the destination set, multer will automatically save the file in the destination that I set. I do not really have to get the file name to store it. I can just do `upload.any()`. Or do I need to have the file name in the `upload.any()`.